# How to deploy model trained with SparkR in sagemaker service?

Tags: sparkr, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a training model with k-means and ALG algorithm in sparkR language.
I wanted to deploy the model throw AWS Sagemaker service.
I have ran some inbuilt examples, which uses conda_python3 language, but how it is possible with SparkR .?

Answer (score 0):

A more native and straightforward option is to use the K-means algorithm that is built-in in SageMaker (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/k-means.html ). SageMaker has an implementation for the most popular algorithms from Spark MLLib, which are usually much faster and more scalable than the Spark versions. It is also coming with the benefit that you can use the built-in Docker containers for the training or the hosting as needed.

If you insist on using the model that you trained with Spark, you can follow the instructions of building an image for the inference with your artifacts. It is more complex than the built-in option, but still possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-code-load-artifacts